# How to pass cell of one table from one method to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to use TableCell defined in one method in another method?
How can I pass the cell? There are lots of cells. IS there any shorter way to pass all cells?

Main method:

```
       while (dr.Read())
        {
            // for each student, 4 rows are there
            TableRow row5 = new TableRow(); // marks obtained
            TableRow row6 = new TableRow(); // grade
            TableRow row7 = new TableRow(); // credits
            TableRow row8 = new TableRow(); // GP*C

            Table1.Controls.Add(row5);
            Table1.Controls.Add(row6);
            Table1.Controls.Add(row7);
            Table1.Controls.Add(row8);

            fill_marks(dr,row5,row6,row7,row8);
            assign_grade(dr, row5, row6, row7, row8);
        }
```

fill_marks method fills the row by creating cells and adding to rows.

```
public void fill_marks(SqlDataReader dr, TableRow row5, TableRow row6, TableRow row7, TableRow row8)
{
    TableCell cell5_1 = new TableCell();
    cell5_1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
    cell5_1.Text = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]).ToString();
    cell5_1.RowSpan = 4;
    row5.Cells.Add(cell5_1);

    //name
    TableCell cell5_2 = new TableCell();
    cell5_2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
    cell5_2.Text = dr[1].ToString();
    cell5_2.RowSpan = 4;
    row5.Cells.Add(cell5_2);
}
```

I am trying to use the cells defined in fill_marks in assign_grade.

```
    public void assign_grade(SqlDataReader dr, TableRow row5, TableRow row6, TableRow row7, TableRow row8)
{
    TableCell cell6_6 = new TableCell();
    cell6_6.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
    cell6_6.Text =      ;     // I want to put content of cell5_1 to cell6_6 
    row6.Cells.Add(cell6_6);

}
```

Comment: You could pass an `IEnumerable<TableRow>` as a single parameter

Comment: I didn't understand your solution. Can you please elaborate or send a link to some reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give your TableCell controls an ID then you can use

```
row5.FindControl("cell5_1id");
```

Or if you are confident of the order of the cells you can access them by index

```
row5.Cells[5];
```

Comment: `row5.Cells(5);`
This gives an error.TableRow.Cells cannot be used as a method.

Comment: It worked. Need to use [] instead of (). Thank you. :)

Comment: Sorry about that, I have corrected it - i have been working in a vb.net project for the past few days so got used to using () for arrays.